# Background color change Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi im a beginner to javascript!
im trying to to change color of the body background according to the select color from the form created.
Ive linked the script to the index.html but i cant seem to know why my body background wont change ... something is missing and can't seem to find it need help please.

```
 <style>
        .azure {
        background-color: #F0FFFF;
        }

        .champagne {
            background-color: #F3EACE;
        }

        .cotton-candy { 
            background-color: #FEC8D8;
        }

        .tea-green {
            background-color: #D7ECC9;
    }
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDocument">
        <h2>Changer la couleur de fond</h2>
        <div>
    
            <select name="pastelBgColor" id="pastelBgColor">
                <option value="azure">Azure</option>
                <option value="champagne">Champagne</option>
                <option value="cotton-candy">Cotton Candy</option>
                <option value="tea-green">Tea Green</option>
            </select>
    
            <button id="submit" >Changer</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Script file JS

    
        
    let button = document.getElementById("submit");
    //event 
button.addEventListener('click',  (event) => {

        let listColor = document.getElementById('pastelBgColor').value;
        
        document.getElementById("myDocument").style.backgroundColor = listColor;
    });
```

Comment: Well, the color won't work because they're classes, not variables. Try using the classList.add to add a new class to the selected element.

document.getElementById("myDocument").classList.add(listColor);

Comment: You have to change your className not your style. ListColor returns you a CCS class that contains an HEX color not the HEX color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far so good, but it seems that you're mixing between two different ways to change the `myDocument` background color. I've split the two ways with working samples below to highlight the differences:

### 1) Use ClassName to change myDocument Color

In that case, we need to use `className` to add the selected class from the dropdown to the `myDocument` element as follows:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let listColor = document.getElementById("pastelBgColor").value;

  document.getElementById("myDocument").className = listColor;
});
```

```css
.azure {
  background-color: #f0ffff;
}

.champagne {
  background-color: #f3eace;
}

.cotton-candy {
  background-color: #fec8d8;
}

.tea-green {
  background-color: #d7ecc9;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDocument">
  <h2>Changer la couleur de fond</h2>
  <div>

    <select name="pastelBgColor" id="pastelBgColor">
      <option value="azure">Azure</option>
      <option value="champagne">Champagne</option>
      <option value="cotton-candy">Cotton Candy</option>
      <option value="tea-green">Tea Green</option>
    </select>

    <button id="submit">Changer</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2) Use color value directly from the list

In that solution, we won't use the class name to change the color, instead, we will add colors as values in your `<select>` and add their value directly to `style.backgroundColor` to the `myDocument`. Also we don't need any CSS in that case, please take a look:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
//event
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let listColor = document.getElementById("pastelBgColor").value;

  document.getElementById("myDocument").style.backgroundColor = listColor;
});
```

```html
<div id="myDocument">
  <h2>Changer la couleur de fond</h2>
  <div>

    <select name="pastelBgColor" id="pastelBgColor">
      <option value="#f0ffff">Azure</option>
      <option value="#f3eace">Champagne</option>
      <option value="#fec8d8">Cotton Candy</option>
      <option value="#d7ecc9">Tea Green</option>
    </select>

    <button id="submit">Changer</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that it's totally fine to have `<option>` value different from what the user sees, that's usually the normal scenario.

Comment: With pleasure, @FabioBrizzi